# Blockchain currency on disconnected nodes

Tags: blockchain

I have a conceptual question regarding maintaining blockchain currency on disconnected nodes.

What happens to transaction currency (as in, the blockchain kept current) in situations where (for example) a large network is disconnected from the public network for an extended period of time (or blocked)?  Let's use the example of a country disconnecting itself from the public internet (for all intents and purposes; yes I know that's almost impossible but go with me), but business utilizing blockchain transactions still continues inside the country.

How is blockchain currency (re)established once that country (network of nodes) is reconnected to the public network?  Are transactions verified/sync'd with the public network based on a verifiable transaction time, or what?

Comment: Is there any code you would like help with?

Comment: I think that's an excellent question.

Answer (score 1):

After resync:

- The transactions realized in bigger network will be marked as proper
- The transactions realized in smaller network will have been marked as invalid and will be ignored

External systems usually are protected from problems related to network fragmentation. External system require connection to many nodes in different locations (countries). If payment isn't visible in all locations it isn't accepted at all.

Moreover some cryptocurrencies are protected from network fragmentation. The node which finds that lost connection to nodes in different location will stop accepting new transactions.

Comment: So as I understand, if the world suddenly decides to block Internet traffic to Russia (or Vietnam, or any random country) - Every node in that country would stop functioning...?