# What happens if a node successfully generates a new block but then goes offline or disconnected from the Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

Considering a miner has successfully generated a new block by solving the mathematical puzzle. What would happen if it goes offline or disconnected from other participating nodes in the Blockchain before it could broadcast the new block and sync with the other nodes in the Blockchain?

If I consider the case of a resync after the node is live again, how is that possible since blockchain is a growing list of blocks? Also I am assuming the block is invalid after successive blocks are created after it.

I came across a close enough [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479869/blockchain-currency-on-disconnected-nodes) on SO but it appears to have some lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the miner solved the block then that block solution remains valid so long as:

1. Any of the transactions in that block are not mined and propagated before the miner regains connection and broadcasts the block. A transaction cannot be double spent, and since the block solution (the block hash) commits to the transaction merkle root, it cannot be removed without rebuilding the merkle root and solving the hash again.
2. None of the transaction outputs that were spent by transactions in the miner's block are spent by other transactions in other blocks mined while they were away. Number 1 is really a subset of this, but it is slightly different.
3. The block timestamp is within the valid range (in Bitcoin, the timestamp cannot be greater than 2 hours from the current network time, and cannot be earlier than the median time of the past 11 blocks).

Comment: So from (1): if a block is mined successfully then the compute node goes offline then the block is still valid?
(3): Is the block timestamp more like saying-if a block is mined but couldn't be connected to the main chain within 2 hours then it is invalid?

Comment: (1) yes as long as 2 and 3 are true. (3) Essentially